# SimpleXMLConverter parse xml nodes

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

I'm stuck. How to parse Node with same name child node?
In this example i need nodes with rate attribute.

```
<xml>
<Rates>
  <Rates winrate_cap="9999">
    <Rates rate="323"/>
    <Rates rate="343"/>
    <Rates rate="2338"/>
    <Rates rate="233"/>
  </Rates>
</Rates>
</xml>
```

My response wrapper class:

```
@Root(name = "xml", strict = false)
public class XMLResponse {

    @ElementList(entry = "Rates")
    public List<Rates> response;

    public static class Rates {

        @Attribute(name = "winrate_cap", required = false)
        public String winrate_cup;

        @ElementList(required = false, entry = "Rates")
        public List<Rates> rates;
    }

    public static class Rates {
        @Attribute(name = "rate", required = false)
        public String rate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right way. As you have many Rates here, better name the class more with more context and set the xml name via Annotation.

I've separated the `XMLResponse` and `Rates` classes, but this doesn't make any difference.

The class `XMLRespone` maps the `<xml>...</xml>` part:

```
@Root(name = "xml")
public class XMLRespone
{
    @Element(name = "Rates")
    private Rates rates;

    // ...
}
```

All types for `<Rates...>...</Rates>` is done by `Rates` class (and it's inner classes, which map the structure:

```
@Root(name = "Rates")
public class Rates
{
    @Element(name = "Rates")
    private RateList rates;

    // ...


    public static class RateList
    {
        @ElementList(entry = "Rates", inline = true)
        private ArrayList<RateValue> values;
        @Attribute(name = "winrate_cap", required = true)
        private int winrateCap;

        // ...
    }


    public static class RateValue
    {
        @Attribute(name = "rate", required = true)
        private int rate;

        // ...
    }

}
```

Deserializing your XML gives this output (using generated `toString()`):

```
XMLRespone{rates=Rates{rates=RateList{values=[RateValue{rate=323}, RateValue{rate=343}, RateValue{rate=2338}, RateValue{rate=233}], winrateCap=9999}}}
```